# Ant migration tool delete classes

Tags: apex, ant

I am using standard build file and want to delete some classes. But all files from folder  must be in package, right? So to delete i need to move files to another folder, deleter them from folder and after that use command  and destructive xml to delete from org?

Comment: That's essentially correct. Are you stuck somewhere? Can we help you?

Comment: @sfdcfox no, i just want to confirm that, cause it a little strange to me. Thanks)